# How to detect/listen Android Application's / Activity's running changes from inside a service?

Tags: android, android-activity, broadcastreceiver, android-service

I've running a Service. This service should listen (i.e. per BroadcastReceiver) for Activity/Application start/resume Action, whatever. My goal is to do something, everytime an application starts, or another application is started / resumed, in short, the current front application changes. How can I do this?

Comment: are you hoping to do this with your own application or with some arbitrary other applications installed on the system?

Comment: i want to do this with any installed application. but  i don't want to do sth. with other application (no direct access or manipulation), i only wan't to be informed, if any application comes to front. for now i've a timertask, which detects periodically the current front application via `ActivityManager.getRunningTasks(1).get(0)`. but i've a bad feeling by doing this. is there a more elegant way, i.e. receiving system intents, which hold this information?

Answer (score 1):

Using the recurring check on ActivityManager(like you stated in your comment) is the only way to accomplish it AKAIK.

The system does not broadcast anything that is catch-able by 3rd parties to indicate that an application has been launched.

Do be aware that a recurring task that checks every few seconds will have performance and Battery implications for the device it is running on.

Comment: thank you a lot for your anwser. it's really surprising to me that there's no simple broadcast-solution. so i'm going to test, how expensive my first approach is.

Comment: I think that I wish there were a better way. But they built the system  to aggressively keep Applications separate from each other (the exception being if one or both was made specifically to interact with others). They did this as a security precaution.